# IBM Worklight Project without Cordova features.. I selected Hybrid application

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a Hybrid Application in IBM Worklight. Added android as destination. When I tried compiling it was not able to identify cordova.js or any phonegap code. So when I searched for Cordova.jar or cordova.js, it was no where to be found.

Has anybody faced this issue and any other way of manually fixing it?

Thanks and regards,
Pooran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build a project that has Android (or any other mobile) environment Worklight studio will automatically generate a native Android project containing your web resources in project/apps/your-app-name/android/native folder. This project will be automatically imported into your Eclipse.

Cordova.js and Cordova.jar files are added automatically to this native project.

Comment: Thanks. I closed the project and reopened. I could see these files already in the project.